# Efficiently detecting concurrent insertions using standard SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, db2

### The Requirements

I have a following table (pseudo DDL):

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGE (
    MESSAGE_GUID GUID PRIMARY KEY,
    INSERT_TIME DATETIME
)

CREATE INDEX MESSAGE_IE1 ON MESSAGE (INSERT_TIME);
```

Several clients concurrently insert rows in that table, possibly many times per second. I need to design a *"Monitor"* application that will:

1. Initially, fetch all the rows currently in the table.
2. After that, periodically check if there are any new rows inserted and then fetch
   these rows **only**.

There may be multiple *Monitors* concurrently running. All the *Monitors* need to see all the rows (i.e. when a row is inserted, it must be "detected" by all the currently running *Monitors*).

This application will be developed for Oracle initially, but we need to keep it portable to every major RDBMS and would like to avoid as much database-specific stuff as possible.

### The Problem

The naive solution would be to simply find the maximal INSERT_TIME in rows selected in step 1 and then...

```
SELECT * FROM MESSAGE WHERE INSERT_TIME >= :max_insert_time_from_previous_select
```

...in step 2.

However, I'm worried this might lead to race conditions. Consider the following scenario:

1. Transaction A inserts a new row but does **not** yet commit.
2. Transaction B inserts a new row and commits.
3. The *Monitor* selects rows and sees that the maximal INSERT_TIME
   is the one inserted by B.
4. Transaction A commits. At this point, A's INSERT_TIME is actually
   **earlier** than the B's (A's INSERT was actually executed before
   B's, before we even knew who is going to commit first).
5. The *Monitor* selects rows newer than B's INSERT_TIME (as a consequence of step 3). Since A's INSERT_TIME is earlier than B's insert time, A's row is skipped.

So, the row inserted by transaction A is never fetched.

Any ideas how to design the client SQL or even change the database schema (as long as it is mildly portable), so these kinds of concurrency problems are avoided, while still keeping a decent performance?

Thanks.

Comment: search for "implementing a queue in sql server" or "implementing a queue iwith a table", and BTW which database are you using? I presume it's not all of those you tagged...

Comment: As stated in my question, initial implementation is Oracle with probable implementations for other major database systems in the future...

Comment: I think you'll find it is subtely different on each RBDMS...

Comment: Mitch, that's what I worry about - we'd like to avoid proliferation of database-specific solutions if possible.

Comment: Then hire an expert database developer versed in all the major RDBMS's perhaps?

Comment: @branko - there's no way around it.  The fun/complicated stuff isn't generic, and if it IS it's at least implemented differently between databases.  Also you are aware of the performance issues of using a GUID as a PK or clustering key, right?

Comment: Mitch, even if that were feasible, that would not solve the maintainability problems introduced by several database layers, each doing the essentially same thing but relying on a different codebase. We'd like to cut the problem in its infancy of possible.

Comment: @JNK, The GUID is inconsequential here. This is just a simplified example that tries to extract the essence of the problem. The real data is more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using any of the platform-specific change data capture (CDC) technologies, there are a couple of approaches.

**Option 1**

Each *Monitor* registers a sort of subscription to the `MESSAGE` table.  The code that writes messages then writes each `MESSAGE` once per *Monitor*, i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE message_subscription (
  message_subscription_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  message_id RAW(32) NOT NULLL,
  monitor_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT uk_message_sub UNIQUE (message_id, monitor_id)
);

INSERT INTO message_subscription
  SELECT message_subscription_seq.nextval,
         sys_guid,
         monitor_id
    FROM monitor_subscribers;
```

Each *Monitor* then deletes the message from its subscription once that is processed.

**Option 2**

Each *Monitor* maintains a cache of the recent messages it has processed that is at least as long as the longest-running transaction could be.  If the *Monitor* maintained a cache of the messages it has processed for the last 5 minutes, for example, it would query your `MESSAGE` table for all messages later than its `LAST_MONITOR_TIME`.  The *Monitor* would then be responsible for noting that some of the rows it had selected had already been processed.  The *Monitor* would only process `MESSAGE_ID` values that were not in its cache.

**Option 3**

Just like Option 1, you set up subscriptions for each *Monitor* but you use some queuing technology to deliver the messages to the *Monitor*.  This is less portable than the other two options but most databases can deliver messages to applications via queues of some sort (i.e. JMS queues if your *Monitor* is a Java application).  This saves you from reinventing the wheel by building your own queue table and gives you a standard interface in the application tier to code against.

Comment: thanks for the Option 1, but there may be times when there are no *Monitors* running. Initially there may be no *Monitors* even installed in the system. There really needs to be the separate MESSAGE table, independently of what *Monitors* are doing. Option 2 sounds feasible, but there are still concerns about how do we determine "longest transaction".

Comment: Option 3, of course, is the right solution but is database-specific. It's possible w'll consider some "database agnostic" MQ, such as Apache ActiveMQ, but that would add another layer that needs to be deployed and maintained which is what we'd like to avoid. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions...

Comment: @Branko - You would generally want to keep the existing `MESSAGE` table in Option 1 because, presumably, a new *Monitor* is going to want to retrieve all existing messages.  The `MESSAGE_SUBSCRIPTION` table would be in addition to, not instead of, `MESSAGE`.  For option 2, you can generally set a crazy upper bound on the length of a transaction-- if your standard OLTP transaction is < 1 second, for example, 5 minutes is probably a crazy upper bound.  You could probably push that out to an hour if you wanted.  You're just forcing the *Monitor* to maintain a larger cache.

Comment: I think I agree with you on Option 2. Simply setting a reasonable upper bound on what is expected to be the longest transaction seems like the easiest solution. It is not entirely bullet-proof, but we may actually be able to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to identify all rows added since the last time you checked (i.e. the monitor checks). You have a "time of insert" column. However, as you spell it out, that time of insert column cannot be used with "greater than [last check]" logic to reliably identify subsequently inserted new items. Commits do not occur in the same order as (initial) inserts. I am not aware of anything that works on all major RDBMSs that would clearly and safely apply such an "as of" tag at the actual time of commit. [*This is* not *to say I would know it if such a thing existed, but it seems a pretty safe guess to me.*] Thus, you will have to use something other than a "greater than last check" algorithm.

That leads to filtering. Upon insert, an item (row) is flagged as "not yet checked"; when a montior logs in, it reads all not yet checked items, returns that set, and flips the flag to "checked" (and if there are multiple monitors, this must all be done within its own transaction). The monitors' queries will have to read all the data and pick out which have not yet been checked. The implication is, however, that this will be a fairly small set of data, at least relative to the entire set of data. From here, I see two likely options:

- Add a column, perhaps "Checked". Store a binary 1/0 value for is/isnot checked. The cardinality of this value will be extreme -- 99.9s Checked, 00,0s Unchecked, so it should be rather efficient. (Some RDBMSs provide filtered queries, such that the Checked rows won't even be in the index; once flipped to checked, a row will presumably never be flipped back, so the overhead to support this shouldn't be too great.)
- Add a separate table identify those rows in the "primary" table that have not yet been checked. When a montior logs in, it reads and deletes the items from that table. This doesn't seem efficient... but again, if the data set involved is small, the overall performance pain might be acceptable.

Comment: If all monitors need to see all rows, a single `Checked` column isn't going to be sufficient.  You'd need to store a flag for each monitor for each row which would mean a separate mapping table between monitors and messages.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Oracle AQ with a multi-subscriber queue.

This is Oracle specific, but you can create an abstraction layer of stored procedures (or abstract in Java if you like) so that you have a common API to enqueue the new messages and have each subscriber (monitor) dequeue any pending messages. Behind that API, for Oracle you use AQ.

I am not sure if there is a queuing solution for other databases.

I don't think you will be able to come up with a totally database agnostic approach that meets your requirements.  You could extend the example above that included the 'checked' column, to have a second table called monitor_checked - that would contain one row per message per monitor. That is basically what AQ does behind the scenes, so it is sort of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Stephen, but strictly, we don't actually need to keep the checked flag for **each** message/monitor. We are currently considering a design in which we keep (in the database) a single `OLDEST_UNFETCHED_INSERT_TIME` per running monitor. By carefully exploiting read consistency guarantees made by most modern databases we may actually be able to guarantee the required functionality without being too database specific. Unfortunately, this solution is fairly awkward and easy to get wrong, so we haven't settled on it just yet...

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL, use [PgQ](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PGQ_Tutorial).  It has all those little details worked out for you.

I doubt you will find a robust and manageable database-agnostic solution for this.